# Opinion : avs-device-sdk to build full alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have searched about how to implement Alexa on the raspberry pi but everywhere I was getting an example of sample app only.

I am looking for creating a product using Alexa. Can someone guide me is Avs-device-SDK is the right choice?

And how can I change it's wakeup word once I install it?
I was searching this too and found this issue but didn't get the Idea:
https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/issues/610

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVS-device-SDK is the right place to start.

Right now, the only wake word according to [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/speechrecognizer.html#speechrecognizer-context) is Alexa.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial for building an Alexa prototype on a Raspberry Pi:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/required-hardware.html

And @Rubbal is correct that "Alexa" is currently the only supported wake word for third party Alexa devs.